# Stage SimulatingOneRobot tutorial - is there still a teleop_base package?

Tags: ros, simulation, stage, ros-fuerte, teleop-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the [stage SimulatingOneRobot tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/stage/Tutorials/SimulatingOneRobot), it mentions to install teleop_base.  I couldn't find that package, does it still exist?

I managed to control the erratic robot via:

```
$ roslaunch turtlebot_teleop keyboard_teleop.launch
```

So it looks like the  [stage SimulatingOneRobot tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/stage/Tutorials/SimulatingOneRobot) should be updated to use this command, or whatever the most appropriate command for controlling the erratic robot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54078/stage-simulatingonerobot-tutorial---is-there-still-a-teleop_base-package?/) by [tleyden](https://answers.ros.org/users/3760/tleyden/) on ROS Answers with karma: 79 on 2013-02-02

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[Possibly related answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/9207/teleop_base-deprecated-need-generic-teleop-package/). Substitution is suggested.

I also found that someone [this](https://github.com/Quizzarex/teleop_base) on github.

I haven't tested neither of them but HTH.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tleyden](https://answers.ros.org/users/3760/tleyden/) on 2013-02-07**:
Thanks!  That helps clears things up a bit.

**Comment by [tonyParker](https://answers.ros.org/users/15131/tonyparker/) on 2014-09-12**:
@Isaac, yes this also works with this too